# How to test parent method called from child component?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm using enzyme and jest and I want to test that parent method is called when child props is called.

I have something like this

```
class Parent extends Component {

  method = () => {...}

  render() {

    <Child propMethod={method}/>
}
}
```

And in test I do something like this

```
let shallow;

function setup() {
    const props = {
        mockMethod: jest.fn()
    };

    const enzymeWrapper = shallow(<Parent {...props}/>);

    return {
        props,
        enzymeWrapper
    };
}
    beforeAll(() => {
        shallow = createShallow({ dive: true });
    });

describe('components', () => {
    describe('Child', () => {
        it('should call method', () => {
            const { enzymeWrapper, props } = setup()
            const component = enzymeWrapper.find(Child)
            component.prop('propMethod')();
            expect(props.mockMethod).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

        })
    });
});
```

But I get

```
Expected number of calls: 1
Received number of calls: 0
```

Test structure is from Redux docs

[here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#components)

Comment: passing something as a prop to `Parent` does not mean it will replace class method. And you don't need that. What does `Parent.prototype.method()` do on being called? Does it update `<Parent />`? Does it provide different props to `<Child />`? Does it call some Parent's callback prop?

Comment: @skyboyer it calls action from redux, from mapDispatchToProps

Comment: @skyboyer my idea was to simply check if the method correspond with the prop function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mock method isn't making it to the child prop.  From the comments what you probably want to do is test that when the method is called, it has some meaningful side effect.  If it's ultimately dispatching a redux action, test that the action was dispatched when the child method is called.

You will have to do something like this anyways if you intend to give your present test any real constraint on the component behavior, so testing that directly is more straightforward and meaningful.

Comment: You are right. I reworked my test so that after the call of child method I check if expected action was dispatched, in parent method